# ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-env'

Tags: typescript, require, npm-start

I'm trying to run 'npm start' in the project. It is showing 
"ERROR in [at-loader] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-env'."

Along with this, I'm getting the following error as well: 
'TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.'

Someone, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information in order to help.  Please add your `tsconfig.json` file to the question.  What kind of project is this and what development tools are you using?  What command is `npm start` running?  (You can get it from the `package.json` file.)